# How does java.util.Random guarantee thread safety on the nextGaussian method?

Tags: java, random, thread-safety

According to the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()) the `nextGaussian` mehtod is implemented as:

```java
 private double nextNextGaussian;
 private boolean haveNextNextGaussian = false;

 public double nextGaussian() {
   if (haveNextNextGaussian) {
     haveNextNextGaussian = false;
     return nextNextGaussian;
   } else {
     double v1, v2, s;
     do {
       v1 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
       v2 = 2 * nextDouble() - 1;   // between -1.0 and 1.0
       s = v1 * v1 + v2 * v2;
     } while (s >= 1 || s == 0);
     double multiplier = StrictMath.sqrt(-2 * StrictMath.log(s)/s);
     nextNextGaussian = v2 * multiplier;
     haveNextNextGaussian = true;
     return v1 * multiplier;
   }
 }
```

How can it be guaranteed to be thread safe when the `haveNextNextGaussian` isn't atomic? Wouldn't it be possible for 2 threads to call the function at the same time so that both threads read `haveNextNextGaussian` as `true` and then both would set it to `false` and effectively returning the same value on both threads?

Comment: Note that the API documentation does not say that it is literally implemented like this. It says: "...implemented *as if by a threadsafe version of the following*". The code shown shows how it functions, but not exactly how it is actually implemented. Thread-safety has been omitted from the example code.

Comment: In the real code (java 11), `nextGaussian` is a `synchronized` method.  That's how it gets thread-safety.

Comment: Yeah I checked  the implementation on openjdks github but totally missed the `synchronized` keyword. @StephenC You should probably make your comment into an answer.